# How does the complexity of calculating the Permanent imply the NP completeness of directed 3-cycle cover?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

In their paper [Two Approximation Algorithms for 3-Cycle Covers](http://wwwhome.math.utwente.nl/~mantheyb/conferences/APPROX2002_BlaeserManthey_3CycleCovers.pdf) of Markus Bläser and Bodo Manthey it is stated that:
*"...deciding whether an unweighted directed graph has a 3-cycle cover is already NP-complete. This follows from the work of Valiant [16] (see also Garey and Johnson [7, GT 13])."*

However I can't see what of Valiant's paper [The Complexity of Computing the Permanent](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82500417.pdf), resp. the [simplified version](https://shaih.github.io/pubs/01perm.pdf) by Ben-Dor and Halevi, should imply the stated NP-completeness; also GT13 *Minimum Bottleneck Path Matching* of Garey and Johnson seems to have no obvious relation to the stated complexity.

> **Questions:**
>
> - why does the NP-Completeness of deciding the existence of a directed vertex-disjoint cycle cover follow from Valiant's complexity result of calculating the Permanent?
> - what is the transformation that demonstrates the equivalence of the Minimum Bottleneck Path Matching and deciding the existence of a directed vertex disjoint 3-cycle cover?

I have already done extensive googling, but could not find anything that could be cited as a proof of the claimed complexity of deciding the existence of a directed vertex-disjoint 3-cycle cover.

Comment: rather unexpectedly I found a proof for the NP Completeness of the directed disjoint cycle cover in [Floodlight Illumiation of Infinite Wedges](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi5vMi03rHrAhUjsKQKHUixA6I4ChAWMAF6BAgCEAE&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.cs.washington.edu%2Ftr%2F2004%2F10%2FUW-CSE-04-10-04.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Xek3_Fy1Wz4U3CdRpsH2Z) via a reduction from Vertex Cover.

Comment: [Computation that counts](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi6z-uK0orxAhUpxoUKHUSnC7A4FBAWMAR6BAgDEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.csie.ntu.edu.tw%2F~lyuu%2Fcomplexity%2F2006%2F20061221.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1yVJgJJ4xHIF8q7l0ioagl) provides a detailed illustration of the reduction of 3Sat to cycle cover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look in Garey and Johnson I find that [GT 13] is **PARTITION INTO HAMILTONIAN SUBGRAPHS** which is the problem of deciding if a $3$-cycle cover exists in a digraph. So, this could be used as a reference for the complexity. Also, Garey and Johnson cited the Valiant paper for this NP-complete problem.

I took a look at the paper by Valiant linked in the question. If I understand correctly the proof of Lemma 3.1 gives the NP-hardness. The proof takes an instance of 3-SAT and constructs a weighted digraph so that the permanent of the adjacency matrix is some constant times the number of solutions of the 3-SAT instance. However, the weights are chosen so that cycle covers with cycles of length 1 or 2 will cancel. Hence, to my understanding the number of solutions to the 3-SAT instance in the number of 3-cycle covers of the digraph. In particular, there is a 3-cycle cover if and only if the formula is satisfiable.

Comment: Thats a very helpful explanation! I will reread Valiant's paper paying more attention to the part you pointed out.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. The construction in the paper is a little vague. It cites [23] and [9] where the ideas come from. I assume more details are in those papers, but I cannot find them.

Comment: At least I managed to unearth [Paul Peter Herrmann's thesis: On Reducibility Among Combinatorial Problems](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/mit/lcs/tr/MIT-LCS-TR-113.pdf)

Comment: Strangely, L.G. Valiant's own cited 1974 paper [23] *"A polynomial time reduction of satisfiability to Hamiltonian circuits that preserves the number of solutions"* doesn't even appear on his [own list of publications](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~valiant/)

Comment: Good find with the thesis. That other Valiant paper is cite as "manuscript" maybe it never made it further.

Comment: Today I sent an email to L.G. Valiant asking for making the (contents of the) manuscript available; let's hope for a positive answer.

Comment: A gadget for reduction to 3D Matching can be found in Sarah Pantel's 1994 thesis [Graph Packing Problems](https://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk1/tape9/PQDD_0028/MQ51442.pdf) on pages 59ff; there the problem is called *Packing with Directed Cycles*. There directed cycles of minimal length 3 are denoted by $\vec{C}_3$, which Iike for its compactness and expressiveness.